# Regex with regcomp/regexec

Tags: regex

Simple question...

I am trying to make this regex work with C functions `regcomp`/`regexec`.  It does not.

```
(?=.*\d.*)(?=.*[a-zA-Z].*).{6,10}
```

Two questions:

1. What does:
   `?=.*` mean?  Could you please break this down in simple terms?
2. Why doesn't this work with regcomp().

I know your inclination is to tell me what a fool I am, and how dare me come in here and ask such a question.  Google it you **_**.  Thanks, okay I am an idiot, I know.  Okay.  Ha ha the joke is on me and I am public about my silly newbie questions.

BTW I am well aware of the fact that regex syntax is different from one system to another.  That is my frustration with this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 1):

1: `(?= ... )` is a *lookahead*. It checks to see if the RegEx inside is found behind your string. In this case, it is checking if your string contains at least a digit and any case character; also the entire string should be between 6 and 10 characters in length.

Also, it's not working because it needs to be: `(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])^.{6,8}$`.